# career account change email

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

After the merge or the career and stackoverflow website, it correctly found my account and linked it. However the email used was the email from my school, which I do not have access to anymore.

Will it be a problem in the future ? And how can I change it since it will appear in my conversation with (eventual future) recruiters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the "edit CV" page while you're logged in. You can get there from either stackoverflow.com/jobs...

[image: edit CV from /jobs]

...or from your Stack Overflow profile:

[image: edit CV from profile]

From there, hover over the top section of your CV and click "edit".

[image: edit]

You'll then see an email address field. Update that to whatever you'd like to use for contact with companies.

Changing your email address on your CV will *not* change the email address you use to log in to Stack Overflow.